# cakephp group based permissions

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, acl

I would like to have group based restrictions that would allow users to access only specified parts of the web. I am new to the whole ACL stuff and I didn't quite get it from the manual :/ therefore I would like to ask some questions.

But before any questions, my routes look like this:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/admin/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/registered/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'registered', 'registered' => true));
```

1.) How do I restrict users from any other group than `Administrator` to access ONLY the `/registered/` part of the web

2.) How do I prevent anyone from using the default addresses like `www.example.com/users/add` on a global scale (I want only `www.example.com/admin/users/add` or `www.example.com/registered/users/add` type of addresses)? This kind of addresses is not event set in the `routes.php` but they still work.

Any answers apprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is a working sollution. (`/app/app_controller.php`)

```
function beforeFilter() {               
        if ((isset($this->params['admin']))) {
            $admin_grp = $this->UserGroup->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'UserGroup.name' => 'Administrator')));
            if ($this->Auth->user('user_group_id') != $admin_grp['UserGroup']['id']) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access denied.', true));
                $this->redirect("/registered");
            } else {
                $this->layout = 'admin';
            }
        } else if (isset($this->params['registered'])) {
            if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Access denied. You need to login first.', true));
                $this->redirect("/users/login");
            }
            $this->layout = 'registered';
        } else {
            $this->layout = 'default';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly is this cake 1.3 or 1.2?
In 1.3 prefix routing is used. You can setup multiple prefixes, for example right now I am developing a site that requires administrator control through admin/controller/action and also I am restricting some areas to only registered users.. for example /users/controller/action.

This is relatively easy to do, first step is to setup prefixes in your core.php:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'registered'));
```

It is documented here:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/950/Prefix-Routing

Auth component can take care of everything else here, you can use ACL and so on but I haven't looked to far into this because it seems overcomplicated for the things I am creating at the moment.

A tutorial I found helpful was Andrew Perkins auth component tutorial on youtube when I was learning how to do this.
youtube.com/watch?v=FjXAnizmR94

There are 3 parts, and he explains things well.

Best of luck!

Comment: Sry, forgot to mention I am using cake 1.3

Comment: Check out the tutorials and the documentation. If you are still stuck I'm sure I can help :-)